# How to show filterGroupItems in the filterbar?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following filterbar:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="ch.example.northwind.controller.Customers"
    xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="{i18n>title}" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavPressBack">
        <content>
            <fb:FilterBar reset="onReset" search="onSearch" showRestoreButton="true" showClearButton="true" showGoOnFB="false">
                <fb:filterGroupItems>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A" label="Company" labelTooltip="Tooltip GroupItem Example">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="B" label="Customer">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G2" groupTitle="Group2" name="A2" label="Supplier" labelTooltip="Tooltip GroupItem Example">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G2" groupTitle="Group2" name="B2" label="Category">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                </fb:filterGroupItems>
            </fb:FilterBar>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

and it looks like:

[image]

How to make `FilterGroupItem G1` visible on the bar?
As you can see on the bar, it says:

> To show filters here, add them to the filter bar in Filters

what does it mean? I can not find filters property.

Answer (score 0):

The filters are there if you click on the Filters, they are not shown as default however.

To make them visible by default in the code you can set the property visibleInFilterBar to true for your FilterGroupItem. For example:

```
<fb:FilterGroupItem visibleInFilterBar="true" groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A" label="Company" labelTooltip="Tooltip GroupItem Example">
    <fb:control>
         <Input type="Text"/>
    </fb:control>
</fb:FilterGroupItem>
```

The instruction `To show filters here, add them to the filter bar in Filters` refers to the usage in the application. In your screenshot there is the button "Filters" on the right side. This is the "Filters", that is referred to. If you click on this you will be able to see all your filters. If you select the checkbox, they will appear in the Filterbar. They are just not added as a default.